# Join two csv files

Tags: python, linux, csv, join, awk

csvfile1

```
status,longitude,latitude,timestamp    
ok,10.12,17.45,14569003    
ok,11.34,16.78,14569000
```

csvfile2

```
weather,timestamp,latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2
rainy,14569003,17.45,10.12,17.50,11.25    
sunny,14569000,13.76,12.44,16.78,11.34
```

expected output

```
status,weather,longitude,latitude,timestamp    
ok,rainy,10.12,17.45,14569003    
ok,sunny,11.34,16.78,14569000
```

I would like to combine the columns longitude,latitude and timestamp of both the files.

There are two longitudes and two latitudes in csvfile2. So i want to compare if it matches any one of the longitude-latitude pairs along with the timestamp.

And the column name order is also different in both the files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

***join_csv.awk*** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=",";   # field separator
    print "status,weather,longitude,latitude,timestamp"  # header line
}
NR==FNR && NR>1 {          # processing the first file
    a[$4]=$1 FS $2 FS $3   # accumulating the needed values (status, longitude, latitude) 
}
FNR>1 {                    # processing the second file
    if ($2 in a) {         # if `timestamp` matches                                                                                                                                             
        split(a[$2],data,FS);  # extracting items for further comparison
        if ((data[2]==$4 || data[2]==$6) && (data[3]==$3 || data[3]==$5)) {
            print data[1],$1,data[2],data[3],$2
        }
    }
}
```

***Usage***:

```
awk -f join_csv.awk file1 file2
```

The output:

```
status,weather,longitude,latitude,timestamp
ok,rainy,10.12,17.45,14569003
ok,sunny,11.34,16.78,14569000
```

Comment: The code works well sir. But its printing only the second line.     `status,weather,longitude,latitude,timestamp ok,sunny,11.34,16.78,14569000`

Comment: @Varadarajan, that's because you have redundant spaces at the end of some lines. Open both files in editor and you'll see. You have to remove them

Answer (score 3):

You can use it.

```
import pandas as pd

first = pd.read_csv('csvfile1.csv')
second = pd.read_csv('csvfile2.csv')

merged = pd.merge(first, second, how='left', on='what you want(it can be label or a list)')
merged.to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

for more details, You can see these [link1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) .[link2](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)
both are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will help you:

```
import csv
file1 = open("csvfile1.csv", "r")
file2 = open("csvfile2.csv", "r")

file1_dict = csv.DictReader(file1)
file2_dict = csv.DictReader(file2)

new_file = open("new_file.csv", "w")
csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["status", "weather", "longitude", "latitude", "timestamp"])
for f1_row, f2_row in zip(file1_dict, file2_dict):
    f1_row, f2_row = dict(f1_row), dict(f2_row) # In python2 no need to convert to dict
    if f1_row["timestamp"] == f2_row["timestamp"]: #Here write the condition to check your latitude and longitude also.
        csv_writer.writerow([f1_row["status"], f2_row["weather"], f1_row["longitude"],  f1_row["latitude"],  f1_row["timestamp"]])

file1.close()
file2.close()
new_file.close()
```

Got output:

```
status,weather,longitude,latitude,timestamp
ok,rainy,10.12,17.45,14569003
ok,sunny,11.34,16.78,14569000
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 11, in <module>
    if file1_row["timestamp"] == file2_row["timestamp"]: #Here write the condition to check your latitude and longitude also.
KeyError: 'timestamp'
I am getting this error

Comment: The header name "timestamp" available in your both csv file?

Comment: @Varadarajan : I updated the code. can you check with latest?. From the error it seems. The conflict between the version of  "python2" and "python3".

Comment: same error sir. tried with python2.7 and python3.5. Can you post the output you have got ?

Comment: space is occur in "csvfile1" headers. After timestamp. So put comma after the "timestamp" column in header of csvfile1. like: **status,longitude,latitude,timestamp,**.